# Is there a term for dynamic forms?

Tags: forms, webforms

Google recently updated its login page, such that they now ask for the username and the password on separate pages. This makes things easier because then I just type in the username, hit enter, then type the password. For novice users (who are not fans of tabbing) this is definitely more usable.

[image: Login form on Google]

I also came across this company that uses this concept to incrementally fill forms, questionnaires, etc.. This is a link to the website: http://www.typeform.com/examples/#Forms

I want to do some research to see if there has been studies on how users perceive these types of forms compared to standard ones. But I am missing the right keywords.. Is there a certain term to describe this type of forms?

Comment: I think this is actually just a wizard type of form. That is at least what I would start searching with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular wizard just applied to login screens.

I think it's to make development easier and more "dynamic".

- if username is stored in cookies then just show password
- if multiple usernames are stored cookies then show the list
- if from a different computer/region/country etc ask extra questions,
  etc etc

This can also be their way of stopping auto login from scripts/bots.

Hope this helps.